# Add max and min height CSS

Tags: html, css

I have following div

```
<div id='a'>
    <div id='b'>Some text</div>
</div>
```

I want to set **Max height** of parent to 100px and child div to 70% and when parent div grows to 100px add scroll bar to child div.

I tried following but parent div does not grow beyond 70px.

**Example**

```css
#a {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DAE3F3;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
#b {
  height: 70%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'>Some text</div>
</div>
```

Here is **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcn8e8xb/1/)** link

Comment: because you have set `#b width` to 70%

Comment: [You need to set some sort of pixel based `max-height` on the child, like this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xLavu8y6/) The child doesn't doesn't care about its parents max height when it overflows with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `overflow-y: scroll;` and `min-height: 70%;`

```css
#a {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DAE3F3;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    min-height:70px;
    max-height:100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#b {
    display: block;
    min-height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
    <div id='b'>Some te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome ttextSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSomextSome te textSometextSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome extSome te textSometextSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome extSome te textSometextSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome e te textSometextSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSometextSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSomee textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome te textSome text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No my parent div should first increase to 100px and only after that add overflow

Comment: I need position absolute in child div

Comment: @Richa Since absolute positioned elements don't expand as their content grow, you have to use `position: static;` or `position: relative;` http://jsfiddle.net/akmgqtjf/

Comment: text overflows over the bottom padding of outer div

Answer (score 0):

Your parent div will never go to `100px` because your child div's height is `70px`, set child div `min-height` to 70% instead:

```
#b {
       min-height:70%;
       max-height:100px;
   }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/wcn8e8xb/2/)

Comment: why can't we use % value for max-height?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `absolute` positioning, instead of `height` and `min-height`, try using `bottom: 30%`.

The 10px padding is affecting the height now. remove it and test. Use another wrapper div, if needed, to add the 10px padding.